# What does JPA EntityManager.getSingleResult() return for a COUNT query?

Tags: java, orm, jpa

What does `EntityManager.getSingleResult()` return for a COUNT query?

So.. what is the precise runtime type of foo?

```
Object foo = em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(t) FROM com.company.Thing t WHERE prop = :param")
       .setParameter("param", value).getSingleResult();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COUNT(t) specifically returns java.lang.Long. When its appears on its own in this context it is returned as-is.

(In other contexts the Long generated by COUNT may be wrapped, but not today.)

Answer (score 53):

As per the [JPA specification](https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3_0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/), COUNT returns a Long:

> #### 4.8.4 Aggregate Functions in the SELECT Clause The result of a query
>
> may be the result of an aggregate
>   function applied to a path expression.
>
> The following aggregate functions can
>   be used in the SELECT clause of a
>   query: AVG, COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM.
>
> For all aggregate functions except
>   COUNT, the path expression that is the
>   argument to the aggregate function
>   must terminate in a state-field. The
>   path expression argument to COUNT may
>   terminate in either a state-field or a
>   association-field, or the argument to
>   COUNT may be an identification
>   variable.
>
> Arguments to the functions SUM and AVG
>   must be numeric. Arguments to the
>   functions MAX and MIN must correspond
>   to orderable state-field types (i.e.,
>   numeric types, string types, character
>   types, or date types).
>
> The Java type that is contained in the
>   result of a query using an aggregate
>   function is as follows:
>
> - **COUNT returns Long.**
> - MAX, MIN return the type of the state-field to which they are applied.
> - AVG returns Double.
> - SUM returns Long when applied to state-fields of integral types (other
>     than BigInteger); Double when applied
>     to state-fields of floating point
>     types; BigInteger when applied to
>     state-fields of type BigInteger; and
>     BigDecimal when applied to
>     state-fields of type BigDecimal.
>
> If SUM, AVG, MAX, or MIN is used, and
>   there are no values to which the
>   aggregate function can be applied, the
>   result of the aggregate function is
>   NULL.
>
> If COUNT is used, and there are no
>   values to which COUNT can be applied,
>   the result of the aggregate function
>   is 0.
>
> The argument to an aggregate function
>   may be preceded by the keyword
>   DISTINCT to specify that duplicate
>   values are to be eliminated before the
>   aggregate function is applied.
>
> Null values are eliminated before the
>   aggregate function is applied,
>   regardless of whether the keyword
>   DISTINCT is specified.

Comment: When we use native query, then this method returns BigInteger instead of Long. Can anybody explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 27):

NB : there's a difference between **JQPL** and **Native** query

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(p) FROM PersonEntity p " );
```

`query.getSingleResult().getClass().getCanonicalName()` --> **java.lang.Long**

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PERSON " );
```

`query.getSingleResult().getClass().getCanonicalName()` --> **java.math.BigInteger**

Answer (score 24):

Native queries can return different objects for a COUNT based on the database driver; however, all those objects extend java.lang.Number, which implements the longValue() method.

Comment: I used to do something like *Integer.parseInt(q.getSingleResult().toString());* to keep my code "robust", but a cast to Number might be a cleaner solution...

Comment: I wish I didn't upvote the other answer, because this one is way below than it deserves.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK COUNT function returns Long

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, a number which is the count from the query:) Its type by specification is Long.

Answer (score 1):

You can return directly integer, rather than a long.

```
return query.getSingleResult() != null ? Integer.parseInt(query.getSingleResult().toString()) : 0;
```

Comment: second call to query.getSingleResult()   will throw Exception Caused by: org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!.
Instead use 


 Object obj = query.getSingleResult();
  if (obj != null) {
   Integer result = Integer.parseInt(obj.toString());
   return result;
  }

  return Integer.valueOf(0);

Answer (score 0):

```
return query.getSingleResult() != null ? Integer.parseInt(query.getSingleResult().toString()) : 0;
```

> Second call query.getSingleResult() will throw
>   org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!

To avoid the  org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!
 use as below

```
Object obj = query.getSingleResult();
    if (obj != null) {
        Integer result = Integer.parseInt(obj.toString());
        return result;
    }

    return Integer.valueOf(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Count returns long.

Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Mandate " );

return (Long) query.getSingleResult();

Mapped your entity with the Query.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a look at the other answers given already. I think, your one doesn't add anything new or improved to them.