# JPA/Hibernate returning BigDecimal not Long

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm computing a SUM grouped by months

```
Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(qlString);
q.setParameter("program", program);
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Long> resultList = (List<Long>) q.getResultList();
long tend = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

When I pass in two resultsLists (closed:ResultsList of Closed items, closedLate: ResultsList of items Closed late) into a method that computes percentages, I get

```
 javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

.

```
private List<Long> computeOTR(List<Long> closed, List<Long> closedLate) {
    List<Long> monthlyOTR = new ArrayList<Long>();
    long numerator;
    Long denominator;
    for (int i = 0; i <11; i++) {
        numerator = closed.get(i) - closedLate.get(i); <----java.lang.ClassCastException
        denominator = closed.get(i);
        long percentage = (int)(numerator * 100.0 / denominator + 0.5);
        monthlyOTR.add(i, percentage);
    }
    return monthlyOTR;
```

}

In Eclipse debug mode closed is showing as BigDecimal. Why is this when I decalre

`List<Long> resultList = (List<Long>) q.getResultList();`

## EDIT-Hibernate Query:

```
public List<Long> findClosedLateByProgram(String program) {

    long tstart = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //@formatter:off
    String qlString = "with PRJ as ( " +
            "select  trunc(END_DATE) as END_DATE,  " +
            "trunc(NEED_DATE) as NEED_DATE   " +
            "from (SELECT UNIQUE * FROM TEST where PROGRAM_NAME = :program " +
            "AND ACTION_BY_ORG = 'AAA') " +
            "),  " +
            "DATES as ( select add_months(trunc(last_day(SYSDATE)), level-7) as thedate  " +
            "from dual connect by level <= 12  )   " +
            "SELECT nvl(sum(case when NEED_DATE <  trunc(thedate,'mm') AND END_DATE between trunc(thedate,'mm') and thedate then 1 end), 0 ) as CLOSED_LATE  " +
            "FROM  DATES, PRJ  " +
            "GROUP BY thedate ORDER BY thedate";
    //@formatter:on

    Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(qlString);
    q.setParameter("program", program);
    // q.setParameter("today",date, TemporalType.DATE);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Long> resultList =  q.getResultList();
    long tend = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long elapsed = tend-tstart;
    System.out.println("Elapsed Time For Closed But Late: " + elapsed);
    return resultList;
}
```

## EDIT 2

I think I am stuck with a BigDecimal?
http://weblogs.java.net/blog/mb124283/archive/2007/04/java_persistenc.html

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574029/what-does-jpa-entitymanager-getsingleresult-return-for-a-count-query

Answer (score 4):

You should already be getting a warning showing that your cast isn't really checking things fully. [Type erasure](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#Topic3) means that at execution time, there's no difference between a `List<Long>` and a `List<BigDecimal>`. So the cast succeeds, and it's only the later *implicit* cast to `Long` which fails.

Basically you need to change your query to make sure it creates `Long` values instead.

Comment: I see.  My query results list is [33,23,25,29,15,30, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL]  I'm guessing the NULL is switching it to BigDecimal.

Comment: @jeff: No, it will depend on your query itself. It sounds like it thinks it's fetching integer data.

Comment: Your right about that. I just fixed my query to retun 0 instead of NULL and the List is still BigDecimal. The query is just counting Records so yes, just integer data.  If I remove all Generics from my JPA query and then in debug mode inpsect resultsList, it show BigDecimal for my 12 integer value. I don't understand how else to modify the query

Comment: @jeff: Well we can't see your query, which makes it quite hard to help you.

Comment: @jeff: Hmm. It's not clear to me why you're using NVL - I suspect you could just have: `SELECT sum(case when NEED_DATE <  trunc(thedate,'mm') AND END_DATE between trunc(thedate,'mm') and thedate then 1 else 0 end)`

Comment: Originally I didn't use NVL. That produced [33,23,25,29,15,30, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL] (my 1st comment). Using NVL it's [33,23,25,29,15,30,0,0,0,0,0,0]

Answer (score 4):

I just faced the same problem.

One solution is to add scalar (https://stackoverflow.com/a/29479658).

But in my case (Spring data jpa with @Query annotation), I couldn't add it.
One workaround is to get result list as a `List <? extends Number>`  (superclass of Long and BigInteger)

Then you can call the Number's method `longValue()`.

In java 8, your sample could become:

```
List<? extends Number> resultListAsNumber =  q.getResultList();
List<Long> resultList = resultListAsNumber.stream().map(i -> i.longValue()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This solution avoids String convertion and will work if one day hibernate returns Long.

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over the results and convert the objects from String:

```
    Query query = createSQLQuery(sql);
    List<Long> ids = new java.util.ArrayList<Long>();
    java.util.Iterator res = query.list().iterator();

    try {
        while(res.hasNext()){
            ids.add(new Long(res.next().toString()));
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: BigDecimal#longValue()