# Hibernate returns BigIntegers instead of longs

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, long-integer, biginteger

This is my Sender entity

```
@Entity
public class Sender {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long senderId;
...


...

    public long getSenderId() {
            return senderId;
    }
    
    public void setSenderId(long senderId) {
            this.senderId = senderId;
    }
}
```

When I try to execute following query:

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
query.append("Select sender.* ");
query.append("From sender ");
query.append("INNER JOIN coupledsender_subscriber ");
query.append("ON coupledsender_subscriber.Sender_senderId = sender.SenderId ");
query.append("WHERE coupledsender_subscriber.Subscriber_subscriberId = ? ");
    
SQLQuery q = (SQLQuery) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(query.toString());
q.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Sender.class));
q.setLong(0, subscriberId);

return q.list();
```

The following error occures:

> ERROR: org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor - HHH000123: IllegalArgumentException in class: be.gimme.persistence.entities.Sender, setter method of property: senderId
>
> ERROR: org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor - HHH000091: Expected type: long, actual value: java.math.BigInteger

This happens because the senderId in the class Sender is actually a long instead of a BigInteger (which is returned by Hibernate).

I was wondering what the best practice was in a case like this, should I be using BigIntegers as id's (Seems a bit of an overkill)?

Should I convert the query results to objects of class Sender manually (That would be a pitty)? Or can I just make Hibernate return `long` id's instead of `BigInteger`s? Or any other ideas?

I'm using Spring, Hibernate 4.1.1 and MySQL

Comment: is there any big integer type in your db? Make sure your objects mapping are right.

Comment: Yes, they are all of type BIGINT(20). But those are tables generated by Hibernate.

Comment: There are lots of things unclear here. Your mapping should be right to the db whatever the reason are. I exclude implicit boxing, unboxing and casting issues. `Transformers.aliasToBean` may map wrong db fields to class object if you have mixing names.

Comment: @erencan I have added my Sender entity to the question. But I don't think the long id's should not be Mapped BIGINT(20) to MySQL (What other type would be correct in MySQL?).

Comment: can you change BIGINT(20) to int? because BigInteger can not be cast to long implicitly.

Comment: Okay, I have added annotation @Column(columnDefinition = "INT") to private long senderId. Now the code works. Tnx! Could you add this as an answer?

Comment: Yes i will add. you are welcome.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The default for ".list()" in hibernate appears to be BigInteger return types for Numeric.  Here's one work around:

```
session.createSQLQuery("select column as num from table")
  .addScalar("num", StandardBasicTypes.LONG).list();
```

Comment: Yep, the default Hibernate behaviour is the problem here. You can also override this at a global level by registering a custom SQL dialect with the call registerHibernateType(Types.BIGINT, Hibernate.LONG.getName()); in the constructor.

Comment: in case of hql query addScalar is not a function then what should be the alternative please let me know

Comment: @dom Not sure, maybe repose it as a new question and add the link here :)

Answer (score 6):

Adding to #Hedley comment to fix it globally you can add a line in SQLDialect constructor.
In my project it was like:

```
public PostgreSQLDialect() {
        super();
        registerHibernateType(Types.BIGINT, StandardBasicTypes.LONG.getName());
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

In older versions of Hibernate you can use

```
  session.createSQLQuery("select column as num from table")
 .addScalar("num", Hibernate.LONG).list();
```

Answer (score 2):

Object database mapping is wrong. There is a casting exception here saying database field is `BigInteger`, but object property is `long`.

`BigInteger` is a special class to hold unlimited size integer values. Furthermore, `BigInteger` can not cast to long implicitly.

To avoid this error database field which is `BigInteger` should be change to `long` compatible type. Change it to a `int` type where int can be casted to `long` implicitly.  See [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).