# mysql native query returns BigInteger and not Integer

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data-jpa

I've been looking for a solution but i cant find anything.
I'm using spring data and in trying to convert string to integers using mysql "convert" but the query returns a list of BigIntegers. how do i get Integers Instead?

my query:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT CONVERT(SUBSTRING(p.loginName,? + 1), UNSIGNED) as num FROM Player p where p.loginName REGEXP  CONCAT(?,'[0-9]*$') ORDER BY num;")
```

The query finds a all the loginNames that matches the regexp, cut the number part and sorts them.

Comment: Call intValue() on your BigIntegers?

Comment: is there a way to it as integer directly from the query result?

Comment: Just a thought -- int primitives are signed and you appear to be asking for something unsigned. I'm guessing that you're not getting int because your code theoretically returns something bigger, and the returned type is reflecting this. Have you tried specifying a signed int in your query?

Comment: i checked for signed and it still returns BigInteger

Comment: Looks like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758347/hibernate-returns-bigintegers-instead-of-longs#29479658) may help.